# mysql stored procedure oddity

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I learned today through [this section of the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) that prepared statements cannot be performed in stored functions, but, as of MySQL version 5.0.13, they can be performed in stored procedures.

Today I was putting together a stored procedure and thought initially it might be interesting to try doing an INSERT statement in it as a prepared statement. However, despite this supposedly being possible (I'm using MySQL 5.5.14), the ? parameter marker in the statement string caused MySQL to throw a syntax error.

I threw a couple of simplified examples together using the same exact sort of syntax I used for the prepared INSERT statement. I'm hoping I just have a syntax error somewhere I just haven't caught. The first block, below, is the procedure that works, i.e. it uses the standard CONCAT(your query string) syntax.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TestConc;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE Procedure TestConc()
BEGIN
  SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE Foo (FooID INT) ENGINE = InnoDB');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  SET @tn := 'Foo';
  SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @tn, ' VALUES (5)');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Upon calling the procedure with this code, the expected happens; 5 is stored in the FooID field of the newly-generated Foo table. However, if we change the lines between the two DEALLOCATE PREPARE directives to this:

```
SET @tn := 'Foo';
SET @sql := 'INSERT INTO ? VALUES (5)';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @tn;
```

We get an error that tells us to check the syntax of the statement near '? VALUES (5)'.

Is it just not possible to substitute a parameter marker for a table name? I haven't tried doing something along the lines of 'SELECT ? FROM Foo' to see if this will work yet. Also, and I don't know if it's important, I've been trying this using MySQL Workbench 5.2.35 CE, rather than a command line.

I don't have any specific need to run queries as prepared statements within procedures ATM, I just want to make sure I have the syntax correct for doing so if I ever should need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter '?' cannot be used for identifiers. Use first variant. From the reference - *Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth.*

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just not possible to substitute a parameter marker for a table name?

No, it's not possible. If you ever think you need this feature, it could be a sign that you have a bad table design.

If you *really* need to specify the table at runtime, you can use dynamic SQL but be careful not to introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Interesting... The INSERT statement wasn't especially important; I was hoping to create some general-purpose stored procedures for some common tasks. Specifically, I wanted to adapt something along the lines of the PersonName function on [this page](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html) such that it was not tied to a specific table. I can see why that would be a bad idea, though.